# Use BrightnessContrast class in Gdiplus C++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gdi+

I am currently using Graphics, Image, Color, and Bitmap Gdi+ classes in my C++ Application, but whenever I try to use [BrightnessContrast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [BrightnessContrastParams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I get errors:

**In Intellisense:** Error: Namespace 'Gdiplus' has no member 'BrightnessContrast'

**When Compiling:** 'BrightnessContrast' : is not a member of 'Gdiplus'

What gives? I did find a [forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/7cb9ce0e-1782-49b3-bc48-9549b8b0ab90/) that said to add a line to "Additional Manifest Dependencies:" in the project properties, I did this but it still didn't work. The post goes on to say try looking in %windir%\winsxs if that doesn't work but I don't see how to make sense of the files in that directory. I am using VisualStudio 2010 on Windows7 64bit.

Also, I am aware that I can create my own Brightness and Contrast functions. I am wondering why I can't use the build-in Classes that are documented on MSDN.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These members are only available in GDI+ version 1.10, the version that shipped first with Vista.  You have to explicitly opt-in to use them.  Like this:

```
#define GDIPVER 0x110
#include <gdiplus.h>
```

Beware that your program won't run on XP when you do this.